# ¿Qué es lo que imprime un caracter con mascara binaria en char?

Tags: c, operador, caracteres

No entiendo por qué el siguiente programa imprime `1 2 4 8 0`
cuando lo imprimo usando `%c`. Entiendo qué imprimirá cuando utilizara `%d` pero usando `%c` imprime una cosa totalmente diferente. ¿Cómo debería pensarlo?

```
int main()
{
    int c=48;
    int i,mask=1;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf(" %c",c|mask);
        mask=mask<<1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahi corregi lo de %c me habia olvidad de cambiarlo,no imprime letras ,imprime numeros ,yo pense que sucedia eso pero no,a eso va mi duda ,no se como pensarlo para saber que da.

Comment: Ah, es que las "letras" que te está imprimiendo resultan ser números en este caso porque estás trabajando con el código ASCII de los dígitos. El valor inicial de `c` es 48, que es el código ASCII del `'0'`

Comment: Si,ya lo entendi ,gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si revisas la tabla de côdigos ASCII, el decimal `48`, (hex `0x30`) corresponde al caracter `'0'`.

Al hacer la operacion or `|`, entre 48 y los números del for obtienes:

```
c or mask                 resultado  %d   %c
48 | 1   =  0x30 | 0x01 =   0x31  =  49 = '1'
48 | 2   =  0x30 | 0x02 =   0x32  =  50 = '2'
48 | 4   =  0x30 | 0x04 =   0x34  =  52 = '4'
48 | 8   =  0x30 | 0x08 =   0x38  =  56 = '8'
48 | 16  =  0x30 | 0x10 =   0x30  =  48 = '0
```

'

Comment: En la última fila, donde dice `49`, debería decir `48`

Answer (score 2):

Es normal que `%c` y `%d` impriman cosas diferentes; porque son cosas diferentes.

---

Según la documentación de [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) al usar `%c`:

> Imprime **un solo carácter**. El argumento primero se convierte a `unsigned char`. Si se usa el modificador `l`, el argumento primero se convierte a cadena de caracteres como cuando se usa `%ls` con un argumento `wchar_t[2]`.

Respecto al uso de `%d`:

> Convierte un **entero con signo** a su representación decimal *[-]dddd*. La precisión especifica el número mínimo de dígitos que deberán aparecer. La precisión por defecto es `1`. Si tanto el valor a convertir como la precisión es `0`, la conversión resulta en ningún carácter.

Por lo tanto, cuando usas `%c` te imprimirá el caracter si éste tiene representación en tu sistema, usando `%d` te imprimirá el valor numérico del caracter.